# Firebase database not showing in listview

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to get data from firebase database.

The data is showing when i try to Toast it. But its not showing in my listview.

Here is the code inside my class.

```
mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mListView);
spinner = (ProgressBar)  view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),username,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/"+username);
usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                final String cuid = ds.child("cuid").getValue(String.class);
                String name = ds.child("cuname").getValue(String.class);
                final String newname = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
                chatRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats").child(cuid + " " + username);
                chatRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String senderid = ds.child("senderid").getValue(String.class);
                            String message = ds.child("message").getValue(String.class);
                            String syou;
                            if (!senderid.equals(cuid)) {
                                syou = "You: ";
                            } else {
                                syou = "";
                            }
                            map.put("name", newname);
                            map.put("lastchat", syou + "" + message);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),newname+" : "+message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            arraylist.add(map);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"NO RESULT!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

This Toast is working, but the list is not showing in my listview.

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),newname+" : "+message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here is my adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    boolean expanded = false;

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                                 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView name, lastchat;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        resultp = data.get(position);

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(resultp.get(FragmentAll.name));
        lastchat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastchat);
        lastchat.setText(resultp.get(FragmentAll.lastchat));

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

I tried to search about this problem but i cant find a solution to my problem.

Hope someone can help me about this.

Thank you.

Comment: Try setting the `Adapter` after `arraylist.add(map);`

Comment: it duplicate the result. maybe because of the for loop.

Comment: Yes. Try after the loop.

Comment: `addValueEventListener()` is an asynchronous call, it returns immediately. While it's still in the process of fetching  new DataSnapshot, you're setting the adapter with a list which doesn't have any elements in it. You should wait for the asynchronous call to finish and then set the adapter or notify data change to adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener` .

Then do,

```
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

after initiallizing recycler view,
and then

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

after getting data on onDataChange()

Comment: working but it just loop the same result.

Comment: you may have adapter notify inside for loop.

Comment: can you edit my script anf post it as answer? i always get same result. it just looping one value. thanks

Comment: https://gist.github.com/har2008preet/1294775fd41c74afa62459ff15617e2b

Comment: i tried your answer but it just show same value. like joe, joe, joe, joe, joe, joe.

Comment: debug and find what is in the arrayList just before adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 1):

You should also call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the second `onDataChange()`:

```
   arraylist.add(map);
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I also use the OnError so I don't lose time when the problem is somewhere else.

Also, please note that `Toast` takes an `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: working but it just loop the same result.